# Declaring a constant with a parameterized width

Tags: verilog, hdl, parameterization

I want to declare constants with a parameterized width.
For example, in this piece of code:

```
module mux2to1 #(parameter w = 4) (output [w-1:0] O, input [w-1:0] i0, i1, input Sel);
  assign O = (Sel)? i1 : i0;
endmodule

module M1 #(parameter n = 4) (input [n-1:0] A, input F, output [n+1:0] B);
  mux2to1#(n+2) mux (B, XXX, XXX, F);
endmodule
```

In the XXXs, I would like to put all 1s for one of them, and for the other, I would like to put 0s followed by a single 1.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the replicated concatenation operator to construct a constant:

```
mux2to1 #(n+2) mux (B, {(n+2){1'b1}}, {{(n+1){1'b0}}, 1'b1}, F);
```

`{(n+2){1'b1}}` creates a constant of `n+2` `1'b1` bits.  Since `n` is 4,  `{(n+2){1'b1}}` is the same as `{6{1'b1}}`, which is the same as `6'b11_1111`.

`{(n+1){1'b0}}` is the same as `5'b0_0000`, then just concatenate a single `1'b1` to that.